# CSS Font-weight -unseen differences?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I made this simple [**demo**](http://jsbin.com/azazil/3/edit).

I can see in Visual studio , all the values which `font-weight` can have :

[image]

However when I tried all those values, I could locate only 4 distincts.

[image]

I added those red rectangles so you can see who has the same width.

**why** those all in the middle ( and those last) looks the same ?  why do I need all those numbers?

Comment: Because some specific fonts may support all those weights (and if not the browser _may_ simulate them). Just for example the Segoe UI font comes with Light, Semi Light, Bold and Semi Bold variants.

Comment: @Adriano and where is the mapping between Semi-xxx etc to numbers?

Comment: Mapping is defined in the browser (but some general rules to resolve weights exists in CSS specifications, for example in [CSS 2.1 read section 15.6](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Different fonts have different font weights available to them. Your browser is not attempting to simulate the missing weights (which is a good thing, that is hard to get right), so you are limited to the weights that exist in the installed version of the font you are using.

Answer (score 6):

This can be either because the font doesn't support so many different weights or the browser can't display those weights.

Regardless, the numbers have to be there because that's how font weights work. If a font *does* support different weights then it is up to the browser to display it as accurately as it can; otherwise it tries to fall back gracefully to the nearest that's supported.